# How to calculate the number of pages of a process, and the size of the page table(in bytes)?

Tags: process

I just need a second opinion on the result that I got for a question to see if it is right.

I am dealing with a computer system using paging, where the address space space of every process has a size of C = 2<sup>c</sup> bytes and the page size is S = 2<sup>s</sup> bytes. Each entry in the page uses E bytes. 
I am trying to calculate the number of pages of a process, and the size of the page table (in bytes)?

My solution:

Number of pages of process = 2<sup>c</sup>/2<sup>s</sup> = 2<sup>c-s</sup>

Size of page table = 2<sup>c-s</sup> × E bytes

I will be grateful for a second opinion in case I made a mistake.

Comment: In principle, yes.  My biggest issue would be, multiple use of S & C.  If I said S = 3, where would you apply it.   Page Size or Bytes?

Comment: I would apply it to bytes. I think...can you elaborate on your suggestion please?

Comment: I agree with your calculation.

Comment: That is assuming that the page table lookup can operate on a simple array. If you have something like a modern PC, a table always occupies an entire page, you have multiple levels of tables, and a table needs to be allocated if it has valid entries.

Answer (score 0):

This formula works as long as the page table size is less than or equal to the frame size. If not, another level of page table is established.